# Difference between "Rate of growth of a function" and "Order of growth of a function"

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, terminology

My question might probably sound stupid, however at the moment I am trying to put all the things in line for certain computer science topic, and I realized that my knowledge in “english mathematics” is just not enough (I do have a solid background in Russian variant, however Computer Science for some topics is pretty much in English language only, so I am desperate to match terms).

To cut the long story short, when speaking about *how fast the function grows*. Are **RATE** of growth and **ORDER** of growth have the same meaning? Or these definitions have different meaning? Or one is subset of another, like Order of growth is classification of Rates of growth?

I will really appreciate reference to a book or publication where I can read everything with some context and make things clear.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think "rate of growth" is common in English. I think it's ambiguous: some people would interpret it to mean the derivative, and others would interpret it to mean the order of growth. You should probably just use "order" when talking about asymptotic complexity classes.